# How to remove Press ENTER message in vim easyMotion plugin

Tags: vim

I'm using Vim with EasyMotion plugin. My current .vimrc is following: https://github.com/iAdramelk/.dotfiles/blob/master/vimrc

I'd like how this plugin works, bot every time I tried to move with it it prints following message and didn't move until I hit enter:

```
EasyMotion: Jumping to [222, 41]                                                                                                                                              
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

There is no such behavior in EasyMotion demo at it's repo. So I'm assuming that there is some bug in my config. But even if I disable all plugins and `set` options bug still persists.

How can I fix this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed bug by uninstalling vim (installed by homebrew with flag `--with-features=big`), and then reinstalling it from here `homebrew/dupes/vim` in huge configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Do you consume the plugin through GitHub, or an official version from the vim.org website? This looks like some debugging statement left in the plugin code.

You could work around the problem by using `:silent` in its mappings, or increasing `'cmdheight'`, but I would really contact the plugin author to fix the root cause.

Comment: Plugin is installed from https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion via vundle. I don't know how to add silent in this case: This is not the action that a made a key binding to, it is called from inside the plugin after I start in already.

Comment: Yeah, you would have to replicate part of the mapping done inside the plugin, if that's actually possible. As I said, having the author fix it is preferred.